# What are the services that MROs provide for corporate jets (private jets)?

Tags: cost, aircraft-maintenance

What are typical Costs/Rates of Private(corporate jets) MRO Services in the Middle East/North Africa region?

Comment: Is there a particular country or area you are interested in?

Comment: yes MENA region !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the MRO services for corporate jets includes, but is not limited to:

- Aircraft major and minor inspections and overhaul
- Aircraft defect rectification and trouble shooting
- On-site defect rectification (away from base).
- Compliance of regulatory directives.
- Replacement of avionics units.
- Aircraft engine maintenance.

The costs associated with these activities will vary depending on the model, location and aircraft condition. If you want actual costs, it would be best to contact the service provider directly.